# Folding at home stuck on "Connecting"

Tags: connection, raspberry-pi-os, 64-bit

## Information

Hello. I'm having some issues with the Folding@Home Client for raspberry pi. I am using a raspberry pi 4 with the 64bit version of Raspberrypi OS (Found here: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2021-05-28/)
I have the client, control, and viewer installed already, I am just having problems getting started. I have been able to get Folding at home operating on a different computer (A PC, if it helps).

## Problem

When I open FAHControl (from the application menu in the top right) the window pops open. However, most of the window is gray and unresponsive. There is some text saying, "Client: Local Connecting Inactive". I configured the client directly by editing the config.xml file (When I opened the control for the first time, no window or pop-up allowed me to configure the client first before trying to connect). In the top bar of the control, the "Configure" tab does not allow me to do much. All I have access to is the "Connection" tab, no others.

## My Research So Far

I have been able to find other forms on this same topic but none have helped (2 to be exact). Most claim it is a port issue but I am not sure how to open or close a port. From my very little knowledge of how F@H works, I think it is a conflict issue. As stated above, I have F@H operational on a PC. The PC is running F@H almost constantly. Both the PC and Raspberry pi are connected to the same Wifi. Also, I have had very similar issues on my laptop, so I think it is a sort of interference problem rather than a firewall/port issue. Thank you.

Comment: what is ***a conflict issue***?

Comment: Sorry for my non-official naming. What I mean is, I wonder if there is an issue because I have a different computer using the same port.

Comment: have you ever had two computers using folding@home before? Anyway, since Folding@home is all outward connections, ***the same port*** will never be an issue

Comment: Yes, I have but recently I've had a lot of problems with getting it to work. I would have my PC running F@H, then I would open F@H on my laptop. It would work the first time but any other time I tried to run both at the same time, I would have to uninstall and reinstall F@H on my laptop. Also, the port issue was just my thought but with my limited knowledge, I kinda thought I would be wrong. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who made the same mistake as I did, after combing through some F@H forum posts, the F@H control will not start the client. This is why it was stuck on connecting. It was trying to connect with the client but the client wasn't running. In order to run the client, you have to type `FAHClient` into the terminal. Then you can open F@H Control and proceed from there. (https://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=36676&p=348018&hilit=Raspberry+pi#p347883)